# Firestore realtime database rules : how to use .matches with auth.token.email?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to check that a new Post received, contains the string corresponding to a specific email 
(contained in auth.token.email, let us say toto@tata.com. We used google-sign and that user is authenticated)

The regular expression below is mainly searching for the string "auth.token.email" which is not what we need.

It should search for toto@tata.com

```
{
  "rules": 
  {   
    "Posts":
     { 
      ".validate" : "newData.val().matches(/auth.token.email/)" 
     }  
  }
}
```

The syntax above must miss something, but I could not find it on internet so far

thanks

Additional note:
I tried also this rule below, but it does not work too (return FALSE)

```
".validate" : "newData.val().contains(auth.token.email)"
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems this is not feasible (I do not need to implement it anymore) as not many (no one) would want to implement that model